# Idiomatic way to encrypt file in macOS?

Tags: macos, encryption

When I am running Linux and want to encrypt a file that contains sensitive information, I run `gpg -c filename` and enter a password when prompted.

What is the common way to do this on macOS?

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use [gpg on osx?](https://sourceforge.net/p/gpgosx/docu/Download/)

Answer (score 4):

On macOS, you can install gpg via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and other methods.

```
brew install gpg
```

As far as encryption tools that come with the OS, you can create encrypted disk images through Disk Utility (and the related command line tools):

[image: Disk Utility Encryption]

You could open such a disk image on a Mac without installing additional software.

Comment: What kind of encryption format does Mac's Disk Utility use, simlar to LUKS?

Comment: @Xen2050 It's like a regular DMG, but the majority of the file is encrypted using AES with a key derived from the password. I'm not sure if a proper file format specification is publicly available.